# How can one design a a custom table or table list in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, qtablewidget

I have a certain task to do and I my table widget looks like this:
[image]

What I want to do is to make my table look like this: [image]

So naturally my question is how do I go on about that?

Answer (score 1):

Multiple solutions exists to style it as you want

- [Qt Style Sheets](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-reference.html): provides styling functionality similar to CSS.
- Reimplement your own [`QStyledItemDelegate`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstyleditemdelegate.html). This allows you to use the `QPainter` functionality to draw each cell exactly like you want.
- Use [QML](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-index.html). This may be the easiest approach to create highly customised GUI's.